# Como percorrer um array a cada click em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, array

Estou a tentar fazer um `Image Viewer` para multi page *TIFFs*. 
Estou a usar uma `PictureBox` e dois botões - um para descer e passar para a página seguinte, e um para subir e passar para a página anterior.

O meu código percorre o array em questão mas quando eu carrego no botão para baixo, percorre o array e vai para a última página do TIFF, em vez de percorrer uma página de cada vez.

Este é o código do meu botão de descer - `downbut`:

```
int tamanho;
int idx1 = 1;
public string[] filestiff; 
private void downbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tamanho = filestiff.Length;
        do {
            foreach (string file in filestiff) //para cada ficheiro no array
            {
                picturetiff.InitialImage = null;
                Image a = Image.FromFile(file);
                picturetiff.Image = a;
                idx1++;
            }
        } while (idx1 < tamanho);
        if (idx1 == tamanho) //quando chegar ao fim do array
        {
            idx1 = 1;
            downbut.Enabled = false;
            upbut.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

O que tenho que alterar no meu código para que, em cada click no botão, andar apenas uma página em vez de percorrer todas de uma vez?

Obrigada a quem ajudar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa de um loop dentro do botão, só tem que atribuir a nova imagem no click. Exemplo:

```
int idx1 = 0; //Primeira imagem, posição 0
string[] filestiff; 
private void downbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (idx < filestiff.Length-1) //só avança se o índice atual for menor que o último índice
   {
       idx++;
       Image a = Image.FromFile(filestiff[idx]);
       picturetiff.Image = a;
   }
}
private void upbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (idx > 0) //só volta se o índice atual for maior que 0
   {
       idx--;
       Image a = Image.FromFile(filestiff[idx]);
       picturetiff.Image = a;
   }
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso! Muito obrigada!

Comment: você pode marcar como resposta @SofiaRodrigues, por nada =]